# NPM Request and multiple page result

Tags: javascript, express, request

I am using request with express in node app. Here is my request function

```
  var request = function (options, callback, args) {
    options.headers = {'User-Agent': 'RETRACTED'};
    options.url = config.api.git.base + '/orgs/RETRACTED/repos?access_token=' + config.tokens.git;

    remoteRequest(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        callback(response, args);
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    });
  };
```

Problem that I have is that GitHub API by itself provides only 30 results per page. What I have in headers is this:

```
Link:  
<https://api.github.com/organizations/RETRACTED/repos?access_token=RETRACTED&page=2>;rel="next", 
<https://api.github.com/organizations/RETRACTED/repos?access_token=RETRACTED&page=3>;rel="last"
```

Now, I can work around this by including parameter in url `per_page=100` to make sure to get 60 repos that my organization has. Now as you might have noticed, that is not the best solution since if we go over 100, somebody will have to update this. On top of everything we have more then couple of hundred issues and I am using same function for them.

This however works only up to 100. From github [documentation](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/) I can see that you can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter

I would appreciate any tip how to request next pages as long as they exist, concat the result in `response` variable I have there and then execute callback.

I remember before seeing an example how somebody is doing it, but I can't seem to find it, so either my terminology is way off when googling or I was tripping and request by itself can't do this?

Edit: One workaround that I found (it does not have url validation for now)

```
var request = function (options, callback, args) {
    options.headers = {'User-Agent': 'RETRACTED'};

remoteRequest(options, function (error, response, body) {
  var links;

  if (!error) {

    if (response.headers.link) {
      links = response.headers.link.split(',');
      links.forEach(function (link) {
        if (link.indexOf('next') !== -1) {
          options.url = link.split(';')[0].replace(/[<>]/g,'');
          request(options, callback, args);
        }
      });
    }

    callback(response, args);
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
});
};
```

I am not sure how much this is viable solution, since callback is being executed after each page, which in this case I don't mind that much since there is only simple logic of saving it in database.

Comment: have you hread of request-promise, I think that would help you here

Comment: just tried using it, still getting just first 30 repos.